# Using curl to upload files

Tags: batch-file, curl, file-upload, cmd, task

I want to automate a file Upload to my webserver using curl. I created a batch file and used Windows Task Scheduler to execute it. When I run the batch file manually with my mouse, it sends the files to my webserver. When Windows Task Scheduler executes the batch file, it does not send files and I get error message :
**'curl' is not recognized as an internal command or external, an executable program or a batch file.**

```
curl -T C:/wamp/www/weblab/vinums/100321092.php ftp://ftp.myhost.com/anatemp/ --user user@myhost.com:mypassword
```

Comment: Try using the full path to curl.  Assuming you are using Windows 10 that would be: `C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe`

Comment: where i put this path ? in task planifier ?

Comment: No you replace `curl` in your batch file command above with it. You should probably also change, `C:/wamp/www/weblab/vinums/100321092.php` to use Windows separators too, i.e. `C:\wamp\www\weblab\vinums\100321092.php`.

Comment: don't work , but the I have resolve this problem in my computer , where i add : Environment Variables in system , path : i add this value : C:\curl-7.75.0-win64-mingw\bin;     the problem is that's not working from another computer

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve that problem, by adding to the Windows > Control Panel > System > Advanced Settings > Environment variable

The path of curl for example : (C:\curl-7.75.0-win64-mingw\bin;)

And it works ... thanks for all